# How to find who last modified the Key vaults in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

How to find who last modified person name in the Key vaults in Azure Portal?.

*I am trying to find the user details who are changing the key vaults public or secret keys in KeyVault in Azure Portal*. Please share your input on this.

Comment: Have you checked activity logs?

Comment: @GauravMantri Hi ,Thanks for the reply,Where do we see the last modified name in the Activity log in key vault.

Comment: @prabhakaranS I have updated my answer with detail steps. Please have a try and let me know.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have verified activity log. But It shows. Is it permission issue or anything missing.. Operation name as ' Policy action.| Status as Succeeded |Time as 40 minutes ago | Apr 24 2020 20:31:24 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | Dev | Azure Policy Insights Thanks

Comment: Which role you are belong to your azure tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GauravMantri said You can by checking user activity log like this way:

[image]

> ***Note:***
>
> 1. Go to your key-vault resource
> 2. Click on Activity log
> 3. Set your `Filter`  By `Key vaults (Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults)`
> 4. Select Your timestamp

Hope you would get your expected results as shown on screen shot.

Comment: I have verified activity log. But It shows. Is it permission issue or anything missing..
Operation name as ' Policy action.| Status as Succeeded |Time as 40 minutes ago | Apr 24 2020 20:31:24 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | Dev | Azure Policy Insights
Thanks

Comment: Did you able to find log? Is there anything I can help with?

Comment: Yeah fins the log. The log shown as "audit policy action ", I am beginner in azure. Could you please share the any tutorials or video links ? Thank you @Md Farid

Comment: Yes sure I can but as you know its a big domain it would be good if you specify which domian knowledge you want to learn

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the last modified modified name, you can use the Actitiy Log and then apply a filter with Resource and select your resource(Keyvault)

[image]

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan,
Thanks, I have verified activity log. But It shows. Operation name as ''audit' Policy action.Any permission issue or anything missing..

Answer (score 0):

In Activity log it shows only if policies are updates or any other updates at resource level not the updates on data

See if diagnostics settings has been updated & then query the resource to find details. See if this helps.

[image: diag settings]

[image: log anl workspace]